# Where to find a table of possible query parameters for Gmail API

Tags: javascript, gmail-api, google-api-nodejs-client

I'm integration the gmail api into my app. And I need list of all possible parameters for query string of gmail.users.messages.list method. https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/reference/rest/v1/users.messages/list
Is there any table of possible values for the method list - "q" parameter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### The query parameter `q` for the Gmail API is based on the search of the Gmail UI

Have a look [here](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/7190?hl=en) at the allowed search operators and syntax.

You can implement it 1:1 into the API request